# Continue taking input in while loop in c. I've tried fflush

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, fflush

I'm learning data structures in C and I need to take input from the user. I learned from searching other stackoverflow questions that I need to use fflush after I print something.

The issue I'm having is when I type add it doesn't print anything until I break the while loop by entering quit twice. Can someone explain how to fix this and why it happens please?

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct S_RacingCar {
    char name[8];
    int speed;

} RacingCar;

const int MaxCars = 4;

void PrintList() {
    printf("List Print...\n");
}

int AddCar(RacingCar *car) {
    printf("Enter Name And Speed:\n\n");
    char input[16];
    fgets( input, 15, stdin);
    int ok = 0;

    int result = sscanf(input, "%s %d", car->name, car->speed);

    if (result == 2) {
        ok = 1;
        printf("Added:%s Speed:%d\n\n", car->name, car->speed);
        fflush(stdout);
    } else {
        printf("Sorry, error parsing input\n\n");

    }

    return ok;
}
int main() {

    RacingCar allCars[MaxCars];
    int numCars = 0;

    char command[16];
    char input[16];

    while( fgets(input, 15, stdin) ){

        sscanf(input,"%s",command);

        if ( strncmp(command, "quit", 4) == 0){
            printf("\n\nBreaking...\n");
            break;
        } else if ( strncmp(command, "print", 5) == 0){
            PrintList();
            fflush(stdout);
        } else if ( strncmp(command, "add", 3) == 0){
            if (numCars < MaxCars) {
                numCars += AddCar( &allCars[numCars] );
                fflush(stdout);
            } else {
                printf("Sorry List is Full!!\n\n");
            }

        }
        fflush(stdout);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get after I type print, and then add is:

```
print
List Print...
add
```

The cursor is left blinking under add. If I enter quit I get:

```
print
List Print...
add
quit
Enter Name And Speed:

Sorry, error parsing input
```

So the program hasn't ended and I'm wondering why. Could someone explain?
To end the program I have to enter quit again:

```
print
List Print...
add
quit
Enter Name And Speed:

Sorry, error parsing input

quit


Breaking...
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
================ READY ================
```

Comment: Well, first setup your includes correctly, including the one you're missing and should have been warned about by your compiler. You should have `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>` (the latter to properly pull in `strncmp`). Regardless of whether/if/how that helps, *its the right thing to do*.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse IDE?

Comment: I'm using notepad++ @CoolGuy

Comment: there are two places where the fgets statement is called. once as a loop control and once for entering the actual data. that is why you need to enter 'quit' twice. I.E. the overall logic needs revision so a single fgets is called that results in either 1) exiting the program -or-  2) sending the data to the addcar function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your program behaves weirdly is because it exhibits UB.

Change

```
int result = sscanf(input, "%s %d", car->name, car->speed);
```

To

```
int result = sscanf(input, "%s %d", car->name, &(car->speed));
```

This is done because `sscanf` expects an `int*` but you give it an `int`.

Also, you can add

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

at the start of `main` and remove all the `fflush()` in your program. The above line flushes the `stdout` whenever it is written to.

Comment: Upticked. This too, would be flagged by reasonable warning levels under most compilers.

Comment: Nevermind! Sorry it works with putting setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); at the beginning of the program. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Sankofa , Try using `setvbuf` and remove all the `fflush` as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, change:

```
int AddCar(RacingCar *car) {
  printf("Enter Name And Speed:\n\n");
```

to:

```
int AddCar(RacingCar *car) {
  fflush(stdout);
  printf("Enter Name And Speed:\n\n");
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `fflush` be placed *after* the `printf`?

Comment: Yea I tried putting it before and it didn't work. Thanks for the reply though. I'm so stuck right now any suggestions could help.